# Digit grouping in Eval function

Tags: c#, asp.net, numbers, format

I have this code in ASP.NET 4.5

```
 <span><%# Eval("Rating").ToString()+" " %></span>
```

to display the rating, but want to group the digits based on the user locale, how can I achieve this directly in aspx without code behind ? 1,000 instead of 1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
<span><%# ((int)Eval("Rating")).ToString("n0")+" " %></span>
```

Or this:

```
<span><%# ((int)Eval("Rating")).ToString("#,###")+" " %></span>
```

**Further Reading**

- [The Numeric ("N") Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#NFormatString)
- [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Comment: with this I get this error in the browser, CS1501: No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Comment: @MarioM Ahh sorry, you probably just need to cast the result of `Eval` to an `int`--you stated in another comment that it was indeed of type `int`, so this should be safe. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Eval("Rating").ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture)
```

Assuming `int` is the return type of `Eval`

Comment: yes it is int, but I get this error now.
 CS0103: The name 'CultureInfo' does not exist in the current context

Comment: It's in `System.Globalization` got to add to using.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
  <%#Eval("Rating","{0:0,00}").ToString() %>
```